# Bixby trigger OAuth flow at specific point in capsule

Tags: bixby

Adding an authorization.bxb file seems to make OAuth based account linking the first step in the app flow. As soon as the capsule starts there is a conversation driver (button) that links to the account linking page. Only once the user completes this flow can they access the rest of the capsule.

[Immediate Account link view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3oa9.png)

How can you customize when the authorization flow begins. For example if your capsule contains some actions that require the user to be authorized and some initial actions that don't require your user to be authorized right away. ie: They can browse freely but if they want to save or purchase they need to link their account.

The [docs for Bixby OAuth](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/actions.using-oauth) don't mention how you can customize where this flow gets invoked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have actions that work with and without oauth.  In your case, you can have 'freemium' flows that allow the user to interact, but other flows would require an OAuth token.  You can control this when you define your endpoint.  Add an authorization to the actions that require a user token.

```
action-endpoint (YourActionName) {
      accepted-inputs (actionInputs) 
      local-endpoint (action.js)

      authorization {
        user
      }
    }
```